# parallelising tf.data.Dataset.from_generator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a non trivial input pipeline that `from_generator` is perfect for...

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(complex_img_label_generator,
                                        (tf.int32, tf.string))
dataset = dataset.batch(64)
iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
imgs, labels = iter.get_next()
```

Where `complex_img_label_generator` dynamically generates images and returns a numpy array representing a `(H, W, 3)` image and a simple `string` label. The processing not something I can represent as reading from files and `tf.image` operations.

My question is about how to parallise the generator? How do I have N of these generators running in their own threads.

One thought was to use `dataset.map` with `num_parallel_calls` to handle the threading; but the map operates on tensors... Another thought was to create multiple generators each with it's own `prefetch` and somehow join them, but I can't see how I'd join N generator streams?

Any canonical examples I could follow?

Answer (score 29):

Turns out I can use `Dataset.map` if I make the generator super lightweight (only generating meta data) and then move the actual heavy lighting into a stateless function. This way I can parallelise just the heavy lifting part with `.map` using a `py_func`.

Works; but feels a tad clumsy... Would be great to be able to just add `num_parallel_calls` to `from_generator` :)

```py
def pure_numpy_and_pil_complex_calculation(metadata, label):
  # some complex pil and numpy work nothing to do with tf
  ...

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lightweight_generator,
                                         output_types=(tf.string,   # metadata
                                                       tf.string))  # label

def wrapped_complex_calulation(metadata, label):
  return tf.py_func(func = pure_numpy_and_pil_complex_calculation,
                    inp = (metadata, label),
                    Tout = (tf.uint8,    # (H,W,3) img
                            tf.string))  # label
dataset = dataset.map(wrapped_complex_calulation,
                      num_parallel_calls=8)

dataset = dataset.batch(64)
iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
imgs, labels = iter.get_next()
```

Comment: FYI, parallelism with `tf.py_func()` might not speed things up by itself, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48781036/5471520).

Comment: good point. empirically though i can say this made a huge speed up.

Comment: Has TensorFlow added `num_parallel_calls` to `from_generator` since your answer?

Comment: @mikkola if not speed things up, any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: do you know why did you get "huge speed up"? Does it mean that even though the point @mikkola made your code is actually running in parallel?

Comment: Have you used this with estimator? I get an error complaining about output_shapes not defined when I do this with keras model estimator. Any help is appreciated!


```
from_genetator
> dataset.output_shapes (TensorShape([Dimension(10), Dimension(32)]), TensorShape([Dimension(10), Dimension(1)]))

after map function
>> dataset.output_shapes (TensorShape(None), TensorShape(None))```

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer generators in python can't be parallelized for a discussion see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13101#issuecomment-501196097

Comment: Such a setup could be beneficial in low memory environments. Maybe the speed-up was the consequence of the computer not swapping anymore.

Comment: Hi, I'm also using from_gerenator() to create tf.data.Dataset. generator is created via simple reading a file then looping through batch_size rows then yield. Since there are no transformation or anything I thought none of operations such as(.cache(), .map()) would be necessary but thought .prefetch() would be useful as it will read data from remote while training however performance(speed of model training) is the same (~few seconds difference). Do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 10):

I am working on a `from_indexable` for `tf.data.Dataset` https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14448

The advantage for `from_indexable` is that it can be parallelized, while a python generator cannot be parallelized.

The function `from_indexable` makes a `tf.data.range`, wraps the indexable in a generalized `tf.py_func` and calls map.

For those that want now a `from_indexable`, here the lib code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
from tensorflow.python.util import nest

def py_func_decorator(output_types=None, output_shapes=None, stateful=True, name=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def call(*args):
            nonlocal output_shapes

            flat_output_types = nest.flatten(output_types)
            flat_values = tf.py_func(
                func, 
                inp=args, 
                Tout=flat_output_types,
                stateful=stateful, name=name
            )
            if output_shapes is not None:
                # I am not sure if this is nessesary
                output_shapes = nest.map_structure_up_to(
                    output_types, tensor_shape.as_shape, output_shapes)
                flattened_shapes = nest.flatten_up_to(output_types, output_shapes)
                for ret_t, shape in zip(flat_values, flattened_shapes):
                    ret_t.set_shape(shape)
            return nest.pack_sequence_as(output_types, flat_values)
        return call
    return decorator

def from_indexable(iterator, output_types, output_shapes=None, num_parallel_calls=None, stateful=True, name=None):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(len(iterator))
    @py_func_decorator(output_types, output_shapes, stateful=stateful, name=name)
    def index_to_entry(index):
        return iterator[index]    
    return ds.map(index_to_entry, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
```

and here an example (Note: `from_indexable` has a num_parallel_calls `argument`)

```
class PyDataSet:
    def __len__(self):
        return 20

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return np.random.normal(size=(item+1, 10))

ds = from_indexable(PyDataSet(), output_types=tf.float64, output_shapes=[None, 10])
it = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
entry = it.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(entry).shape)
    print(sess.run(entry).shape)
```

**Update** June 10, 2018:
Since https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/15121 is merged, the code for `from_indexable` simplifies to:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def py_func_decorator(output_types=None, output_shapes=None, stateful=True, name=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def call(*args, **kwargs):
            return tf.contrib.framework.py_func(
                func=func, 
                args=args, kwargs=kwargs, 
                output_types=output_types, output_shapes=output_shapes, 
                stateful=stateful, name=name
            )
        return call
    return decorator

def from_indexable(iterator, output_types, output_shapes=None, num_parallel_calls=None, stateful=True, name=None):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(len(iterator))
    @py_func_decorator(output_types, output_shapes, stateful=stateful, name=name)
    def index_to_entry(index):
        return iterator[index]    
    return ds.map(index_to_entry, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
```

Comment: unfortunately doesn't stand the test of time because  tf2 doesn't have contrib and py_func has been replaced by py_function which donen't have output_shapes, args, kwargs, stateful. 
And finally, output of py_function returns unknown shape which can' be used inside graph.

Comment: It is true that tf 2.x doesn't have contrib anymore but you can always set the shapes of tensors in a function with the `set_shape` function. You can see an example in the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#applying_arbitrary_python_logic

Answer (score 7):

Limiting the work done in the `generator` to a minimum and parallelizing the expensive processing using a `map` is sensible.

Alternatively, you can "join" multiple generators using `parallel_interleave` as follows:

```
def generator(n):
  # returns n-th generator function

def dataset(n):
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator(n))

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(N).apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(dataset, cycle_lenght=N))

# where N is the number of generators you use
```

Comment: Your code is not valid python code and you did not define `ds` in the first place.

Comment: I really like this. However generator(n) should return the n-th generator, n is a Tensor here. How to get the n-th generator?

Comment: you can give args to from_generator now: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator