# Tensorflow: Load data in multiple threads on cpu

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras

I have a python class `SceneGenerator` which has multiple member functions for preprocessing and a generator function `generate_data()`. The basic structure is like this:

```
class SceneGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self):
       # some inits

    def generate_data(self):
        """
        Generator. Yield data X and labels y after some preprocessing
        """
        while True:
            # opening files, selecting data
            X,y = self.preprocess(some_params, filenames, ...)            

            yield X, y
```

I used the class member function sceneGenerator.generate_data() in keras model.fit_generator() function to read the data from disk, preprocess it and yield it. In keras, this is done on multiple CPU threads, if the `workers` parameter of `model.fit_generator()` is set to something > 1.

I now want to use the same `SceneGenerator` class in tensorflow. My current approach is this:

```
sceneGenerator = SceneGenerator(some_params)
for X, y in sceneGenerator.generate_data():

    feed_dict = {ops['data']: X,
                 ops['labels']: y,
                 ops['is_training_pl']: True
                 }
    summary, step, _, loss, prediction = sess.run([optimization_op, loss_op, pred_op],
                                                  feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

This, however, is slow and does not use multiple threads. I found the [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) api with some [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/programmers_guide/datasets), but I fail to implement the methods.

**Edit:** Notice that I do not work with images so that the image loading mechanisms with file paths etc. do not work here.
My `SceneGenerator` loads data from hdf5 files. But not complete datasets but - depending on the initialization parameters - only parts of a dataset. I would love to keep the generator function as it is and learn how this generator can be directly used as input for tensorflow and runs on multiple threads on the CPU. Rewriting the data from the hdf5 files to csv is not a good option because it duplicated lots of data.

**Edit 2:**: I think something similar to this could help: [parallelising tf.data.Dataset.from_generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086599/parallelising-tf-data-dataset-from-generator)

Comment: I updated my source code to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest Tensorflow (1.4 at the time of this writing), you can keep the generator and use the [`tf.data.*`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data) API as follows (I chose arbitrary values for the thread number, prefetch buffer size, batch size and output data types):

```
NUM_THREADS = 5
sceneGen = SceneGenerator()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(sceneGen.generate_data, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x,y : (x,y), num_parallel_calls=NUM_THREADS).prefetch(buffer_size=1000)
dataset = dataset.batch(42)
X, y = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

To show that it's actually multiple threads extracting from the generator, I modified your class as follows:

```
import threading    
class SceneGenerator(object):
  def __init__(self):
    # some inits
    pass

  def generate_data(self):
    """
    Generator. Yield data X and labels y after some preprocessing
    """
    while True:
      # opening files, selecting data
      X,y = threading.get_ident(), 2 #self.preprocess(some_params, filenames, ...)            
      yield X, y
```

This way, creating a Tensorflow session and getting one batch shows the thread IDs of the threads getting the data. On my pc, running:

```
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run([X, y]))
```

prints

```
[array([  8460.,   8460.,   8460.,  15912.,  16200.,  16200.,   8460.,
         15912.,  16200.,   8460.,  15912.,  16200.,  16200.,   8460.,
         15912.,  15912.,   8460.,   8460.,   6552.,  15912.,  15912.,
          8460.,   8460.,  15912.,   9956.,  16200.,   9956.,  16200.,
         15912.,  15912.,   9956.,  16200.,  15912.,  16200.,  16200.,
         16200.,   6552.,  16200.,  16200.,   9956.,   6552.,   6552.], dtype=float32),
 array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])]
```

**Note**: You might want to experiment removing the `map` call (that we only use to have the multiple threads) and checking if the `prefetch`'s buffer is enough to remove the bottleneck in your input pipeline (even with only one thread, often the input preprocessing is faster than the actual graph execution, so the buffer is enough to have the preprocessing go as fast as it can).

Comment: With X, y from the generator: Would I still use a feed_dict?

Comment: You don't use X and y from the generator, you use those from the iterator.get_next() as input tensors of your model (they go where you're currently using the placeholders). This way, you won't need to feed anything when doing sess.run().

Comment: Ahh, I see! So I just get rid of the placeholders and use X and y instead. And during sess.run() Tensorflow automatically gets the next elements, right? Can I reset the iterator or do I have to create a new one for each epoch?

Comment: That's right, Tensorflow takes care of fetching the next batch from the dataset. The way you coded the generator, the loop is infinite so the iterator won't ever end, but if you want to change that, there is an initializable iterator (have a look at the "reading data" tutorial on the Tensorflow website, I'll put a link here once I'm back on my PC)

Comment: Ok, understood. I should have updated my code here to the state it is in my local scripts. There the generator actually ends after some runs and that finishes my epoch.

Comment: [This is the link to the importing data tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets), it shows the different types of iterators available and how they're used. I suggest you have a look there and if you see something you might find useful comment here and I'll update my answer

Comment: @GPhilo since python has a global interpreter lock will parallelizing the generator still speed up the execution of the code if we use, let's say, cv2 to read and preprocess our images? Should one try to use tf preprocessing functions like tf.read_image or does the speed up come from asynchronized execution of the pipeline and the graph and just a single thread? Thanks!

Comment: Hey! I don't know tbh, but tf.data functions support seamless multi-thread operations (it's usually a matter of specifying how many parallel threads you want for operations like map() ) and in my experience that reaches speeds I don't think I could ever match with a python-only approach. I suggest you try to do as much as you can in TF directly, leaving to python just things you can't do in any other way

Answer (score 3):

Running a session with a `feed_dict` is indeed [pretty slow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2919):

> Feed_dict does a single-threaded memcpy of contents from Python runtime into TensorFlow runtime.

A faster way to feed the data is by using [`tf.train.string_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) + [`*Reader`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ReaderBase) + [`tf.train.Coordinator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Coordinator), which will batch the data in multiple threads. For that, you read the data directly into tensors, e.g., here's a way to read and process a `csv` file:

```py
def batch_generator(filenames):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
  reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
  _, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

  content = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
  content[4] = tf.cond(tf.equal(content[4], tf.constant('Present')),
                       lambda: tf.constant(1.0),
                       lambda: tf.constant(0.0))

  features = tf.stack(content[:N_FEATURES])
  label = content[-1]

  data_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([features, label],
                                                   batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                   capacity=20*BATCH_SIZE,
                                                   min_after_dequeue=10*BATCH_SIZE)
  return data_batch, label_batch
```

This function gets the list of input files, creates the reader and data transformations and outputs the *tensors*, which are evaluated to the contents of these files. Your scene generator is likely to do different transformations, but the idea is the same.

Next, you start a `tf.train.Coordinator` to parallelize this:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for _ in range(10):  # generate 10 batches
        features, labels = sess.run([data_batch, label_batch])
        print(features)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

In my experience, this way feeds the data much faster and allows to utilize the whole available GPU power. Complete working example can be found [here](https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/blob/master/examples/05_csv_reader.py).

Comment: Thank you for your input!
Well, my data is not in csv format but multiple hdf5 files from which I only read parts. I do not want to duplicate the data into csv files, because different parameters in my SceneGenerator would force me to write again all the data to a new set of csv files. My question is therefore precisely, how I can use a python generator for creating the input. I bet there is a more direct way than first writing all the training (and test) data into csv files.

Comment: @Merlin1896 I see. Well, hdf5 support in tensorflow... leaves much to be desired. Do you consider third-party libraries? Like this one: https://github.com/ghcollin/tftables

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will look into this!