# Parallelism isn't reducing the time in dataset map

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

[TF Map function supports parallel calls](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map). I'm seeing no improvements passing `num_parallel_calls` to map. With `num_parallel_calls=1` and `num_parallel_calls=10`, there is no improvement in performance run time. Here is a simple code

```
import time
def test_two_custom_function_parallelism(num_parallel_calls=1, batch=False, 
    batch_size=1, repeat=1, num_iterations=10):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    start = time.time()
    dataset_x = tf.data.Dataset.range(1000).map(lambda x: tf.py_func(
        squarer, [x], [tf.int64]), 
        num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls).repeat(repeat)
    if batch:
        dataset_x = dataset_x.batch(batch_size)
    dataset_y = tf.data.Dataset.range(1000).map(lambda x: tf.py_func(
       squarer, [x], [tf.int64]), num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls).repeat(repeat)
    if batch:
        dataset_y = dataset_x.batch(batch_size)
        X = dataset_x.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        Y = dataset_x.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        i = 0
        while True:
            try:
                res = sess.run([X, Y])
                i += 1
                if i == num_iterations:
                    break
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError as e:
                pass
```

Here are the timings

```
%timeit test_two_custom_function_parallelism(num_iterations=1000, 
 num_parallel_calls=2, batch_size=2, batch=True)
370ms

%timeit test_two_custom_function_parallelism(num_iterations=1000, 
 num_parallel_calls=5, batch_size=2, batch=True)
372ms

%timeit test_two_custom_function_parallelism(num_iterations=1000, 
 num_parallel_calls=10, batch_size=2, batch=True)
384ms
```

I used `%timeit` in Juypter notebook. What am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 40):

The problem here is that the only operation in the `Dataset.map()` function is a [`tf.py_func()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) op. This op calls back into the local Python interpreter to run a function in the same process. Increasing `num_parallel_calls` will increase the number of TensorFlow threads that attempt to call back into Python concurrently. However, Python has something called the ["Global Interpreter Lock"](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) that prevents more than one thread from executing code at once. As a result, all but one of these multiple parallel calls will be blocked waiting to acquire the Global Interpreter Lock, and there will be almost no parallel speedup (and perhaps even a slight slowdown).

Your code example didn't include the definition of the `squarer()` function, but it might be possible to replace `tf.py_func()` with pure TensorFlow ops, which are implemented in C++, and can execute in parallel. For example—and just guessing by the name—you could replace it with an invocation of [`tf.square(x)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/square), and you might then enjoy some parallel speedup.

Note however that if the amount of work in the function is small, like squaring a single integer, the speedup might not be very large. Parallel `Dataset.map()` is more useful for heavier operations, like parsing a TFRecord with `tf.parse_single_example()` or performing some image distortions as part of a data augmentation pipeline.

Comment: Nice answer, I have been wondering about how `tf.py_func` works with `num_parallel_calls`! BTW -- the GIL link seems broken.

Comment: Sorry about that: fixed the link!

Comment: After replacing 'th.py_func()' with 'tf.square', increasing num_parallel_calls do not speedup obviously. maybe overhead time is larger than 'tf.square'(or 'tf.py_func')

Comment: @quanly_mc do you have futher conclusion about this, I met the same problem, and doesn't know how to handle it

Comment: @crafet When mapping operation cost long time, increasing `num_parallel_calls` speedup obviously. An example was provided in my answer.

Comment: after what @quanly_mc pointed out, it would be nice that someone clarifies to what extent the GIL prevents the code in `tf.py_func()` to run in parallel.

Comment: The link to `tf.py_func()` is broken.

Answer (score 4):

The reason maybe the squarer cost less time than overhead time. I modified the code with adding a quarter function which cost 2 seconds. Then the parameter num_parallel_calls works as expected. Here is the complete code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time
def squarer(x):
  t0 = time.time()
  while time.time() - t0 < 2:
    y = x ** 2
  return y

def test_two_custom_function_parallelism(num_parallel_calls=1,
                                         batch=False,
                                         batch_size=1,
                                         repeat=1,
                                         num_iterations=10):
  tf.reset_default_graph()
  start = time.time()
  dataset_x = tf.data.Dataset.range(1000).map(
      lambda x: tf.py_func(squarer, [x], [tf.int64]),
      num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls).repeat(repeat)
  # dataset_x = dataset_x.prefetch(4)
  if batch:
    dataset_x = dataset_x.batch(batch_size)
  dataset_y = tf.data.Dataset.range(1000).map(
      lambda x: tf.py_func(squarer, [x], [tf.int64]),
      num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls).repeat(repeat)
  # dataset_y = dataset_y.prefetch(4)
  if batch:
    dataset_y = dataset_x.batch(batch_size)
    X = dataset_x.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    Y = dataset_x.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    i = 0
    while True:
      t0 = time.time()
      try:
        res = sess.run([X, Y])
        print(res)
        i += 1
        if i == num_iterations:
          break
      except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError as e:
        print(i)
        break
      print('step elapse: %.4f' % (time.time() - t0))
  print('total time: %.4f' % (time.time() - start))


test_two_custom_function_parallelism(
    num_iterations=4, num_parallel_calls=1, batch_size=2, batch=True, repeat=10)
test_two_custom_function_parallelism(
    num_iterations=4, num_parallel_calls=10, batch_size=2, batch=True, repeat=10)
```

the output is:

```
[(array([0, 1]),), (array([0, 1]),)]
step elapse: 4.0204
[(array([4, 9]),), (array([4, 9]),)]
step elapse: 4.0836
[(array([16, 25]),), (array([16, 25]),)]
step elapse: 4.1529
[(array([36, 49]),), (array([36, 49]),)]
total time: 16.3374
[(array([0, 1]),), (array([0, 1]),)]
step elapse: 2.2139
[(array([4, 9]),), (array([4, 9]),)]
step elapse: 0.0585
[(array([16, 25]),), (array([16, 25]),)]
step elapse: 0.0469
[(array([36, 49]),), (array([36, 49]),)]
total time: 2.5317
```

So I am confused with the effect of "Global Interpreter Lock" mentioned by @mrry.

Comment: Confused, too.  @mrry

Answer (score 3):

I setup my own version of `map` to get something similar to the TensorFlow's `Dataset.map`, but which will use multiple CPUs for `py_function`s.

**Usage**

Instead of

```
mapped_dataset = my_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(my_function, [x], [tf.float64]), num_parallel_calls=16)
```

with the below code, you can get a CPU parallel `py_function` version using

```
mapped_dataset = map_py_function_to_dataset(my_dataset, my_function, number_of_parallel_calls=16)
```

*(The output type(s) for the py_function can also be specified if it's not a single `tf.float32`)*

Internally, this creates a pool of `multiprocessing` workers. It still uses the single regular GIL limited TensorFlow `map`, but only to pass the input to a worker and get the output back. The workers processing the data happen in parallel on the CPU.

**Caveats**

The function passed needs to be [picklable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) to work with the `multiprocessing` pool. This should work for most cases, but some closures or whatnot may fail. Packages like `dill` might loosen this restriction, but I haven't looked into that.

If you pass an object's method as the function, you also need to be careful about how the object is duplicated across processes (each process will have its own copy of the object, so you can't rely on the attributes being shared).

As long as these considerations are kept in mind, this code should work for many cases.

**Code**

```
"""
Code for TensorFlow's `Dataset` class which allows for multiprocessing in CPU map functions.
"""
import multiprocessing
from typing import Callable, Union, List
import signal
import tensorflow as tf


class PyMapper:
    """
    A class which allows for mapping a py_function to a TensorFlow dataset in parallel on CPU.
    """
    def __init__(self, map_function: Callable, number_of_parallel_calls: int):
        self.map_function = map_function
        self.number_of_parallel_calls = number_of_parallel_calls
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(self.number_of_parallel_calls, self.pool_worker_initializer)

    @staticmethod
    def pool_worker_initializer():
        """
        Used to initialize each worker process.
        """
        # Corrects bug where worker instances catch and throw away keyboard interrupts.
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

    def send_to_map_pool(self, element_tensor):
        """
        Sends the tensor element to the pool for processing.

        :param element_tensor: The element to be processed by the pool.
        :return: The output of the map function on the element.
        """
        result = self.pool.apply_async(self.map_function, (element_tensor,))
        mapped_element = result.get()
        return mapped_element

    def map_to_dataset(self, dataset: tf.data.Dataset,
                       output_types: Union[List[tf.dtypes.DType], tf.dtypes.DType] = tf.float32):
        """
        Maps the map function to the passed dataset.

        :param dataset: The dataset to apply the map function to.
        :param output_types: The TensorFlow output types of the function to convert to.
        :return: The mapped dataset.
        """
        def map_py_function(*args):
            """A py_function wrapper for the map function."""
            return tf.py_function(self.send_to_map_pool, args, output_types)
        return dataset.map(map_py_function, self.number_of_parallel_calls)


def map_py_function_to_dataset(dataset: tf.data.Dataset, map_function: Callable, number_of_parallel_calls: int,
                               output_types: Union[List[tf.dtypes.DType], tf.dtypes.DType] = tf.float32
                               ) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    """
    A one line wrapper to allow mapping a parallel py function to a dataset.

    :param dataset: The dataset whose elements the mapping function will be applied to.
    :param map_function: The function to map to the dataset.
    :param number_of_parallel_calls: The number of parallel calls of the mapping function.
    :param output_types: The TensorFlow output types of the function to convert to.
    :return: The mapped dataset.
    """
    py_mapper = PyMapper(map_function=map_function, number_of_parallel_calls=number_of_parallel_calls)
    mapped_dataset = py_mapper.map_to_dataset(dataset=dataset, output_types=output_types)
    return mapped_dataset
```

Comment: Just one note, "TensorFlow runtime is not fork-safe"- using multiprocess with tensorflow can give some problems there is an old thread talking about it [Tensorflow issue #5448](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5448), in the thread is noted that by using multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn') can help with this.

Comment: @RenanWille, presumably, the user is resorting to using `py_function` because the TensorFlow runtime doesn't support what they want to do, and so they're falling back on Python to handle it. As long as the `py_function` does not contain calls to the TensorFlow runtime, this solution should have no issue. The other processes should only be running Python, which supply the data for the TensorFlow runtime running/waiting in a single process. However, your comment is worthwhile, as people may be trying to mix both Python and TensorFlow pieces in a single method.

Comment: You are a life saver, thank you! How do you go about passing arbitrary parameters such as config objects along with every map call though?

Comment: @aviator, if the config object is going to be the same for every call you could define the map function as a closure that captures that config object. Something more or equivalent but a little more intuitive would be to use [partial](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Partial_functions) to build a function with a parameter sorta "pre-passed in".

Comment: @aviator, if you instead need to update your config object during run and need all the pool functions to update, then either you need to modify the mapper to pass additional information to the pool processes, or have the map function be a method of an object which is somehow watching for a message to update its state from the other processes.

Comment: THANK YOU! This function let me split my super slow py function across 64 cores and eliminate my bottleneck. I definitely suggest opening an issue/pr with tensorflow to see if this could become an official option