# Can Dataset.map somehow parallelize over tf.py_func calls?

Tags: tensorflow

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484689/parallelism-isnt-reducing-the-time-in-dataset-map), `Dataset.map` does not support parallelism over `tf.py_func` calls in the map function (the `tf.py_func` part will execute sequentially).

Is there any workaround for this issue? It is very often the case that input pipelines require complex python control flow and operations that do not exist in tensorflow. In the past I used to implement my own queue and preprocessing threads using python libraries, but it would be very convenient to be able to do it using the convenient `tf.data` interfaces.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, one can work around the limitations of the GIL can by using the python `multiprocessing` library instead of the `threading` library.

Comment: But how to you actually integrate the multiprocessing calls within the tensorflow flow (using the `Dataset` API and so on)?

Comment: From the [Best Prformance with tf.data API Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#parallelizing_data_transformation), it seems like TensorFlow is able to parallelize a py_func. I've tried to find more details on that, but so far without success..