# Data augmentation using python function with tf.Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I'm looking for dynamically read images and apply data augmentation for my image segmentation problem. From what I've looked so far the best way would be the `tf.Dataset` API with `.map` function.

However, from the examples I've seen I think I'd have to adapt all my functions to tensorflow style (use `tf.cond` instead of `if`, etc..). The problem is that I have some really complex functions that I need to apply. Therefore I was considering using `tf.py_func` like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

img_path_list = [...]   # List of paths to read
mask_path_list = [...]  # List of paths to read

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_path_list, mask_path_list))

def parse_function(img_path_list, mask_path_list):
    '''load image and mask from paths'''
    return img, mask

def data_augmentation(img, mask):
    '''process data with complex logic'''
    return aug_img, aug_mask

# py_func wrappers
def parse_function_wrapper(img_path_list, mask_path_list):
    return tf.py_func(func=parse_function,
                      inp=(img_path_list, mask_path_list),
                      Tout=(tf.float32, tf.float32))

def data_augmentation_wrapper(img, mask):
    return tf.py_func(func=data_augmentation,
                      inp=(img, mask),
                      Tout=(tf.float32, tf.float32))        

# Maps py_funcs to dataset
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function_wrapper,
                      num_parallel_calls=4)
dataset = dataset.map(data_augmentation_wrapper,
                      num_parallel_calls=4)

dataset = dataset.batch(32)
iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
imgs, labels = iter.get_next()
```

However, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48781036/6850241) it seems that using `py_func` for parallelism does not work. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

py_func is limited by the python GIL, so you won't get much parallelism there. Your best bet is to write your data augmentation in tensorflow proper (or to precompute it and serialize it to disk).

If you do want to write it in tensorflow you can try to use tf.contrib.autograph to convert simple python ifs and for loops into tf.conds and tf.while_loops, which might simplify your code quite a bit.

Comment: I see, so probably I can't avoid converting everything into tensors. The problem is that my functions are quite complex, involving walking into dirs, loading several images, merging them, processing, etc... I was wondering if processing everything in Python using multiprocess and then pass it using feed_dict would be faster than the tf.Dataset + py_func approach. Do you have an idea about that? Thanks a lot

Comment: multiprocess might let you use more cores, yes. Be careful though because multiprocessing doesn't play well with tensorflow, which has a lot of threads internally (so you want to import tensorflow only after you fork the processes)