# IDE breakpoint in TensorFlow Dataset API mapped py_function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I'm using the [Tensorflow Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) to prepare my data for input into my network. During this process, I have some custom Python functions which are mapped to the dataset using `tf.py_function`. I want to be able to debug the data going into these functions and what happens to that data inside these functions. When a `py_function` is called, this calls back to the main Python process (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48781036/1191087)). Since this function is in Python, and in the main process, I would expect a regular IDE breakpoint to be able stop in this process. However, this doesn't seem to be the case (example below where the breakpoint does not halt execution). Is there a way to drop into a breakpoint within a `py_function` used by the Dataset `map`?

**Example where the breakpoint does not halt execution**

```
import tensorflow as tf

def add_ten(example, label):
    example_plus_ten = example + 10  # Breakpoint here.
    return example_plus_ten, label

examples = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
labels =   [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0]

examples_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(examples)
labels_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((examples_dataset, labels_dataset))
dataset = dataset.map(map_func=lambda example, label: tf.py_function(func=add_ten, inp=[example, label],
                                                                     Tout=[tf.int32, tf.int32]))
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
example_and_label = next(iter(dataset))
```

Comment: Which TensorFlow version are you using? it seems to be working on 1.12.0  
P.S.: make sure the python function returns the correct type (e.g. ´return np.int32(example_plus_ten), np.int32(label)´ )

Comment: @gabriele: 2.0 (currently latest stable version).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tensorflow 2.0 implementation of tf.data.Dataset opens a C threads for each call without notifying your debugger.
Use `pydevd`'s to manually set a tracing function that will connect to your default debugger server and start feeding it the debug data.

```
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace()
```

Example with your code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pydevd

def add_ten(example, label):
    pydevd.settrace(suspend=False)
    example_plus_ten = example + 10  # Breakpoint here.
    return example_plus_ten, label

examples = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
labels =   [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0]

examples_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(examples)
labels_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((examples_dataset, labels_dataset))
dataset = dataset.map(map_func=lambda example, label: tf.py_function(func=add_ten, inp=[example, label],
                                                                     Tout=[tf.int32, tf.int32]))
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
example_and_label = next(iter(dataset))
```

Note: If you are using IDE which already bundles pydevd (such as PyDev or PyCharm) you do not have to install `pydevd` separately, it will picked up during the debug session.

Comment: Hi, I am using flat_map in TF 2.2. and my breakpoint is hit in some strange "interpreted/compiled" temporary code (some `tmpcXXXXXXX.py` file) with `pydevd.settrace(suspend=True)`...do you know? Is there any possibility to avoid that whilst debugging (using pycharm)? thx you in advance, BR gfkri

Comment: @DanielBraun: I am using PyCharm with tensorflow 2.4.1 (in Windows) Setting a breakpoint in the example above does not work. However, if I understand you correctly it should stop since pycharm already bundles pydevd, or?

Comment: @gebbissimo did you get any solution? I am also facing the same problem in Pycharm on windows 10 and using tensorflow 2.5

Comment: Seems it is a known bug, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39320#issuecomment-816515654