# Debugging tf.data.Dataset.map

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow v2.1 and I am confused about [`map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) method in `tf.data.Dataset`. does it really call the `map_func` or just somehow wrap and visuallize the map function?
I was trying to debug what happens in my `map_func` but the debugger did not enter that function at all!!

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275095/ide-breakpoint-in-tensorflow-dataset-api-mapped-py-function