# Why my Tensorflow dataset cannot read data paralleled?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-serving

I used Tensorflow estimator and GPUs to train my model, and dataset to read data. But strangely，the CPU cores that my procedure used is one, which means my procedure cannot read data parallel. But I set `num_parallel_calls=20` in my code, and I have 20 CPU cores in my machine. Here is my `input_fn` code, could someone told me the reason?

The version of tf is 1.14.0 and 3.6 for python.

```
def train_input_fn(filepath,batch_size=32,num_epochs=1,perform_shuffle=False,multi_gpu=True):
     
    def_parse_fn(record):
        features={
            "user_id":tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
            "click_id_list":tf.FixedLenFeature([100],tf.int64)
        }
        parsed=tf.parse_single_example(record,features)
        input_sequence=tf.cast(parsed["click_id_list"],tf.int32)
        return{"input_sequence":input_sequence}

    def_get_local_files(file_path):
        local_path=file_path
        files=os.listdir(local_path)
        file_paths=[]
        for f in files:
            file_paths.append('{}/{}'.format(local_path,f))
        return file_paths

    dataset=tf.data.TFRecordDataset(_get_local_files(filepath),num_parallel_calls=20)
    dataset=dataset.map(_parse_fn,num_parallel_calls=20).prefetch(1000)
 
    dataset=dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    dataset=dataset.batch(batch_size,drop_remainder=False)
    iterator=dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    batch_features=iterator.get_next()
     
    return dataset
```

And here is my code of GPU setting.

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
session_config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options, allow_soft_placement=True)   
mirrored_strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(num_gpus=4)
```

Comment: You can try using  `tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE` for `num_parallel_calls` and see if there is any difference in performance. You can refer this SO post for some details on  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484689/