# Tensorflow Dataset API: parallelising tf.data.Dataset.from_generator with parallel_interleave

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In a production environment I have data coming in from N producers that has to go through a network. I found this comment on [parallelising tf.data.Dataset.from_generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086599/parallelising-tf-data-dataset-from-generator) which really describes what I want.

```
def generator(n):
  # returns n-th generator function

def dataset(n):
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator(n))

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(N).apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(dataset, cycle_lenght=N))

# where N is the number of generators you use
```

However how should the generator(n) function look like. Because when I run this sample with

```
 def generator(n):
        """Returns the n-th generator function (for consumer n)
        """
        consumer = self.consumers[n]

        def gen():
            for item in consumer:
                yield item

        return gen
```

with self.consumers a Python list then I will get the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor

Comment: What is `n`? From the code you posted it sounds like it's a `tf.Tensor`, which can't be used to index into a list.

Comment: Yes, that is why I made this question :)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is *almost* correct, but you're getting an error because the `n` argument in `dataset(n)` is a "symbolic" `tf.Tensor`, and not an actual value that can be used to look up a consumer in `self.consumers`.

Fortunately, there is a workaround, which involves passing `n` through the optional `args` argument to [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator):

```
def dataset(n):
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, args=(n,))
```

Under the covers, `from_generator()` inserts some code to convert `n` to a Python integer before each call to `generator`.