# Parallelizing batching using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

I have a computationally-expensive method for simulating data coded up as a generator that I want to feed into my neural network model in Tensorflow. I would like to quickly generate batches of data by parallelizing the calls made to the generator. My current data input pipeline as shown below:

```
def data_iterator():
     # data generation procedure to be parallelized
     pass

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_iterator, 
                                        (tf.float32,tf.float32), 
                                        (tf.TensorShape([HEIGHT, None, 1]), 
                                         tf.TensorShape([2])))

dataset = dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, 
                               padded_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([HEIGHT, None, 1]), 
                                              tf.TensorShape([2])))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
x_image, y_ = iterator.get_next()
```

Unfortunately, I found that creating a batch of data using the `from_generator()` method cannot easily be parallelized with no way to specify how many threads I use to pull data from the generator to create batches. I tried the solution in this thread(https://stackoverflow.com/a/47089278) which uses a wrapper function and mapping in parallel and found that the speed did not increase at all. Previously, I was using queues to input my data which seemed to work well as follows:

```
class CustomRunner(object):
    """
    This class manages the the background threads needed to fill
        a queue full of data.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataX = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[HEIGHT,WIDTH,1])
        self.dataY = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2])
        # The actual queue of data. The queue contains a vector for
        # the features, and a scalar label.
        self.queue = tf.FIFOQueue(shapes=[[HEIGHT,WIDTH,1],[2]],
                                           dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.float32],
                                           capacity=QUEUE_CAPACITY)
        self.enqueue_op = self.queue.enqueue([self.dataX, self.dataY])

    def get_inputs(self,batch_size):
        """
        Return's tensors containing a batch of images and labels
        """
        images_batch, labels_batch = self.queue.dequeue_many(batch_size)
        return images_batch, labels_batch

    def thread_main(self, sess):
        """
        Function run on alternate thread. Basically, keep adding data to the queue.
        """
        for dataX, dataY in data_iterator():
            sess.run(self.enqueue_op, feed_dict={self.dataX:dataX,  self.dataY:dataY})

    def start_threads(self, sess, n_threads=1):
        """ Start background threads to feed queue """
        threads = []
        for n in range(n_threads):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_main, args=(sess,))
            t.daemon = True # thread will close when parent quits
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
        return threads

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=24, 
                 inter_op_parallelism_threads=24))
```

I had to change this because I couldn't feed dict with variable width. Does anyone know if there's a good solution for this?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what your question is.  Are you trying to parallelize the execution of a generator?  That's not possible. Generators are inherently sequential, that's why things like context managers can be implemented as generators: you're guaranteed to get the results in order one after another.  If that's not true of your data generation logic then it shouldn't be a generator.

Comment: Sorry. Let me clarify. The data_iterator provides a single data point value. I would like to parallelize the process of creating a batch of data (e.g. 50 data points) via 50 calls to the generator. It doesn't seem like tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() easily allows for that.

Comment: Sounds like your data generation should just be a function.  Maybe have a very basic generator that creates the correct number of slots and then `map` the actual data generation onto that?

Comment: I did try that, but the speed stayed the same, so I am not sure if I was simply not properly dedicating enough cores or threads to the operation. Is the correct way to do that via `tf.ConfigProto`..?