# Is it possible to add data from a different source to a Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Is it possible to merge data from a different source into a Tensorflow Dataset. Let's say I have the following data in a Dataset:

```
customer_id  age  name    friend_id
0             25  Max     1
1             39  Moritz  1
2             21  Lilli   2
```

in addition I have a list of dictionaries with complementary data:

```
friend_id  friend_name
1          Mary
2          Terry
```

Is it possible to merge the complementary data into the Dataset? The end result should be something like:

```
customer_id  age  name    friend_name
0             25  Max     Mary
1             39  Moritz  Mary
2             21  Lilli   Terry
```

Comment: possibly ; though it should probably be done before your data is formatted to be fed into a `Dataset`. The `Dataset` api is fairly young and not meant for such joins. If you still want to, I suggest you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086599/parallelising-tf-data-dataset-from-generator

Comment: The question kind of confirms what I was thinking of - using either map + globals or apply, but both ways look really hacky.
I will probably follow your advice and do the join beforehand.